# Динамическое изменение положения элемента при нажатой и удерженной кнопке мыши

Tags: javascript

Господа, интересует только чистый JS. В примере видно, что кликая в определенное место ползунок меняет положение свое, а как сделать так, хочу кликнуть по ползунку и удерживая кнопку мыши менять положение за движением мыши по горизонтали. Ну не соображу ни как логику...

```js
var value;
var rangeWrapper = document.querySelector('#rangeWrapper');
rangeWrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  value = event.offsetX;
})
rangeWrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  slider.style.left = value + 'px';

})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

#rangeWrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
}

#slider {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 111;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
}

#triangle {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 0% 50%, 200% 0%, 100% 75%);
}
```

```html
<div id="rangeWrapper">
  <div id="triangle">
    <div id="bg_grad"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: в обработчике mousemove меняй значение left, в соответствии с текущей координатой мыши, которую можно получить из параметра event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const rangeWrapper = document.querySelector('#rangeWrapper');
const movelistener = event => {
  event = event || window.event;
  let left = (event.pageX - rangeWrapper.offsetLeft);
  if (left < 0) left = 0;
  if (left > (rangeWrapper.offsetWidth - slider.offsetWidth)) left = rangeWrapper.offsetWidth - slider.offsetWidth;
  slider.style.left = left + 'px';
}
window.addEventListener('mouseup', event => window.removeEventListener('mousemove', movelistener));

rangeWrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  slider.style.left = event.ofssetX + 'px';
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', movelistener);
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

#rangeWrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
}

#slider {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 111;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: orange solid 1px;
  background: transparent;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
}

#triangle {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 0% 50%, 200% 0%, 100% 75%);
}
```

```html
<div id="rangeWrapper">
  <div id="triangle">
    <div id="bg_grad"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: так у меня тоже получилось)))  у меня тоже дергался. как я понял, надо при каждом изменении положение ползунка брать не изначальное положение а его текущее положение, я прав?

Comment: @Air нет. Я обновил ответ, теперь не дёргается. Косяк был в том, что положение слева от самого слайдера считалось а не от враппера.

Comment: Не хочу выглядеть наглым, но будь другом, сделай так чтобы он не выходил за пределы, я просто не соображу, как сделать

Comment: @Air обновил ответ

Comment: супер, благодарю

Comment: @Air стоит из left еще вычесть половину ширины слайдера, чтобы он не левым боком, а центром был в нужной позиции

Comment: да да, я тоже об этом подумал, дальше сам доделаю