# Как сделать ползунок?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Добрый день,как можно сделать вот такой ползунок на jquery?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сам ползунок я сделал,но как прикрепить его данные к нему,что бы они плавали вместе с ползунком ?

Comment: мы по картинке должны угадать, как вы сделали, и как надо к этому прикрепить? приведите код вашего ползунка хотя бы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Динамическое изменение положения элемента при нажатой и удерженной кнопке мыши](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731886/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b8)

Comment: посмотрите на [codepen](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=range&page=1&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false) там есть то, что вам нужно