# Как сделать такие ползунки? Никак не могу их реалиховать?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Ребят подскажите какие-нибудь методы и способы решения данной задачи. Буду признателен.

[image: Ползунки получается кастомные. в инете искал чет не могу разобраться..]

Comment: В чём именно возникла проблема, при реалихации?

Comment: 1) стилизация тонкой линии (с одной стороны серый, а где прокручено красный). Не могу сделать такой же тонкой
2) Как сделать чтобы при изменении цифры (18 месяцев - например) - Менялись токо цифры а текст месяцев остался

Comment: @FrondMedia Что вы пытались сделать и что не получилось, приложите код. 
Что пробовали из гугла: [Пример1](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/), [Пример2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63392447/how-to-style-input-type-range), [Пример 3](https://www.cssportal.com/style-input-range/), [интересная дока 4](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp)

Comment: Чтоб понимать лучше как стилизируются элементы можно включить свойство в Хром инспекторе `Show user agent shadow DOM`, тогда проще станет понимат какие есть элементы и как к ним обратится можно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Динамическое изменение положения элемента при нажатой и удерженной кнопке мыши](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731886/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b8)

Comment: Всем большое спасибо! Разобрался по предложенным вариантам и применил у себя)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Библиотека плагинов jqueryui раздел - Slider, подобное действие Snap to increments или Range Slider
https://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps